# Contraparte en Facturas Emitidas SII Usando WCF

Tags: wcf, aeat-sii

En la version 07 , la clase PersonaFisicaJuridicaType no tiene un miembro que se llame NIF tal como dice la documentacion de la AEAT.
Por tanto para definir el NIF uso IDOtroType. Pero no hay manera.
Me responde con el error 
1104 Valor del campo ID incorrecto

```
PersonaFisicaJuridicaType LaContra = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType() ;
LaContra.NombreRazon = NombreRazon ;
//-------------------------------
 IDOtroType ElOtro = new IDOtroType();
 ElOtro.CodigoPaisSpecified = true;
 ElOtro.CodigoPais = CountryType2.ES;
 ElOtro.IDType = PersonaFisicaJuridicaIDTypeType.Item02;
 ElOtro.ID = "23740800Q" ;
        //---------------------------
 LaContra.Item = ElOtro;
 LaFraExpedida.Contraparte = LaContra;
```

Answer (score 1):

El usuario pburgov te lo explicó para Java, como no se en que lenguaje lo estás realizando te explico como lo hice yo en C#.

Siempre que la contraparte o el emisor pueda ser no español, el identificador se guarda dentro de Item.

Item almacena un objeto, que puede ser tanto un string como un objeto IDOtro.

Si la contraparte es española, y por tanto tiene un nif, sería tan simple como:

```
PersonaFisicaJuridicaType LaContra = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType() ;
LaContra.NombreRazon = NombreRazon ;
LaContra.Item = "23740800Q";
LaFraExpedida.Contraparte = LaContra;
```

Por otro lado, si la contraparte no es española, deberás rellenar el objeto IDOtro tal como hiciste.

```
PersonaFisicaJuridicaType LaContra = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType() ;
LaContra.NombreRazon = NombreRazon ;
//-------------------------------
IDOtroType ElOtro = new IDOtroType();
ElOtro.CodigoPaisSpecified = true;
ElOtro.CodigoPais = CountryType2.ES;
ElOtro.IDType = PersonaFisicaJuridicaIDTypeType.Item02;
ElOtro.ID = "23740800Q" ;
//---------------------------
LaContra.Item = ElOtro;
LaFraExpedida.Contraparte = LaContra;
```

El error probablemente se deba a que rellenaste IDOtro (es decir, un identificador extranjero) pero definiste como CodigoPais a España.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días, sí que tiene el campo NIF, al menos a mí me aparece en la implementación que estoy realizando en java. Esta es la clase de java tal cual extraida del archivo `SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl` mediante la herramienta `wsdl2java`

```
public class PersonaFisicaJuridicaType {

@XmlElement(name = "NombreRazon", required = true)
protected String nombreRazon;
@XmlElement(name = "NIFRepresentante")
protected String nifRepresentante;
@XmlElement(name = "NIF")
protected String nif;
@XmlElement(name = "IDOtro")
protected IDOtroType idOtro;
//.........

/**
 * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad nif.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getNIF() {
    return nif;
}

/**
 * Define el valor de la propiedad nif.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setNIF(String value) {
    this.nif = value;
}
//Resto del código de la clase
}
```

Y así lo uso en el código que gestiona el envío a la AEAT

```
private List<LRfacturasEmitidasType> getFacturas() {
    //Instanciamos un array para el detalle de las facturas
    List<LRfacturasEmitidasType> facturasEmitidasList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Factura selectedData : selectedDataList) {
        /*
           Contraparte (PersonaFisicaJuridicaType) 
         */
        PersonaFisicaJuridicaType contraparte = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType();
        contraparte.setNIF(selectedData.getContraparteNIF());
        contraparte.setNombreRazon(selectedData.getContraparteNombreRazon());
        if (!selectedData.getContraparteCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("ES")) {
            IDOtroType otroType = new IDOtroType();
            otroType.setCodigoPais(CountryType2.valueOf(selectedData.getContraparteCountry()));
            otroType.setIDType(selectedData.getIdType());
            otroType.setID(selectedData.getContraparteNIF());
            contraparte.setIDOtro(otroType);
            contraparte.setNIF(null);
        }
//.....
}
```